# I cannot type áéíóú in Linux Konsole or Kate, but I can do it in VS Code or Google Chrome

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint, kde

After an update of Linux Mint KDE 18.2 Sonia, I am having problems with the accented characters.

I cannot write Spanish accents with vowels: `áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ`in Konsole, Kate, Dolphin and some other programs.

However, that problem *does not* appear in LibreOffice, Visual Studio Code, Google Chrome or Spyder.

The problem only affects my session. When I start my Linux using another user, the problem does not appear. On both accounts, I do a `locale`and I get, the same information:

```
daabank@eredron ~ $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
daabank@eredron ~ $
```

Also, I performed a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` without any success.

Some other information is:

```
daalvarez@eredron ~ $ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="latam"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

And:

```
daalvarez@eredron ~ $ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc101
layout:     latam
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Any clue on what to do?

Comment: Odd. Compare the settings output from `locale` with your user versus another user. Chances are you will see different settings. To fix it, you might need to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` on your user to reset locale settings. But since I have no deep experience with Linux Mint I cannot recommend that or post that as an answer with confidence.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, without any success :( Please check my updated entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by writing:

```
 export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

at the end of my `~/.profile` and then rebooting my computer.

Comment: It also word i you add this environment variable to the .desktop icon or to /etc/profile for all users